# GPT4 image prompts

Tags: chat-gpt-4

I am getting this error while trying to attach image to my prompts in GPT4. Can anyone help me with this?[GPT4 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LR8w.png)

I wanted basic image analysis from GPT4 which I have done many times in the past but it has been constantly giving me an error now. Am I missing something here?